# Trying to insert variable in match function in vba

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am getting an error while running this code, cannot understand what's wrong with this:

```vb
i = ActiveCell.End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(r, source, WorksheetFunction.Match("i", msource, 0), 0)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post code in text also include the rest of it so we can provide a solution

Comment: If the lookup fails, `Application.WorksheetFunction.***` *throws* a run-time error instead of returning it as a `Variant/Error` value to the calling cell like a worksheet function does. If `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` is supposed to be an `#N/A` error when the lookup fails, use the late-bound version (careful: no compiler assistance!): `= Application.VLookup(...)` instead of `= Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`.

Comment: `.Match("i", msource, 0)` should be `.Match(i, msource, 0)`. The double quotes are making `"i"` a string literal value so you're matching the literal value "i". Remove the quotes to match the value of the `i` variable.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.WorksheetFunction` invokes worksheet functions, but in the context of VBA code: normally in VBA, when a function throws an error, it comes in the form of a *run-time error*, and that's exactly what these functions do.

So you have two options.

One, handle (or swallow) VBA runtime errors:

```
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Like this, when the right-hand side of the assignment throws an error (i.e. when the lookup fails), the left-hand side won't be affected and the target cell keeps whatever value it had before. Note the `On Error GoTo 0`, which restores runtime errors. This is critically important; without it `On Error Resume Next` will have your code running in some unhandled error state, and that is the single best way to hide bugs and make them pretty much impossible to diagnose later.

Two, use the late-bound version.

When invoked directly against `Application`, worksheet functions are late-bound. You don't get compiler assistance so watch out for any typos and make sure the parameters are good (you don't get a tooltip with a parameters list for late-bound member calls).

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.VLookup(...)
```

It's the same `VLookup` function, but now it behaves like it would on a worksheet, *returning* an error value instead of *throwing* a run-time error like a VBA function would. That makes the target cell value hold a `#N/A` worksheet error when the lookup fails.

Same applies to the inner `Match` function; now while nesting worksheet functions is how we do things in a worksheet cell's formula, doing that in code makes everything much harder than necessary - split things up, evaluate the `Match` separately, validate whether it returned an error value, then pass it to `VLookup` only if it didn't.

```
Dim matchResult As Variant
matchResult = Application.Match(i, msource, 0)
If IsError(matchResult) Then Exit Sub
```

Note that your code is passing the literal string value `"i"` to the `Match` function; you probably intend to pass the value of the `i` variable: you must remove the double quotes around it to do that.

Comment: Helpful not only for newbies as explaining VBA background knowledge one misses in most teaching materials :+)